# Валидация через DynamicModel Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Есть такой метод:

```
protected function validateConfig($config)
{
    $moduleId = $config['moduleId'] ?: null;
    $defaultVersion = $config['defaultVersion'] ?: null;
    $versions = $config['versions'] ?: null;
     $model = DynamicModel::validateData(
        compact('moduleId', 'defaultVersion', 'versions'), [
            [['moduleId', 'defaultVersion', 'versions'], 'required'],
            [['moduleId', 'defaultVersion'], 'string'],
            [['moduleId'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
             [['versions'], function($attribute, $params) {
                 if(!is_array($this->$attribute)){
                     $this->addError($attribute, Module::t('module-manager', 'Versions should be an array'));
                 }
             }],
         ]
     );
     return $model->hasErrors() ? false : true;
}
```

Здесь с помощью DynamicModel мне нужно проверить данные из массива $config.

1. moduleId, defaultVersion и versions должны быть обязательно.
2. moduleId и defaultVersion - строка. Максимум 255 символов.
3. versions - должно быть массивом.

Я использую анонимную функцию в этих целях.

При попытке получить $this внутри функции у меня идет обращение к моему классу, в котором находится метод validateConfig.

Я думал, что DynamicModel создает временную модель со свойствами moduleId, defaultVersion и versions. И я смогу обращаться к ним.

Как правильно написать анонимную функцию для валидации такого рода?

Comment: Ну логично. что $this обращается к классу, а куда нужно?

Comment: К модели, которую динамически создает DynamicModel.

Answer (score 1):

Ну тогда как бы не через статику делайте. Анонимная функция понятия не имеет о существовании модели. И через статику не получится работать с ней, так как она еще не создана, и передать её в **use** не сможете

```
    $model = new DynamicModel(compact('moduleId', 'defaultVersion', 'versions'));
    $model->addRule(['versions'], function ($attribute, $params) use ($model) {
        if(!is_array($model->$attribute)){
            $model->addError($attribute, 'Ахтунг');
        }
    })->validate();
```